# What is difference between "to be" and "to have been" in "This author appears (to be)/(to have been) inspired from his friends"?

Tags: difference, tense, verbs

What is difference between "to be" and "to have been" in this context?

1. > This author appears *to have been* inspired from his friends.
2. > This author appears *to be* inspired from his friends.

It looks like both mean the same. Is there a difference in the meaning?

Comment: *...inspired **by** his friends.* If he appears to be X, that's *present tense* (he definitely seems to be X *at time of utterance*, and possibly did so earlier as well). If he appears ***to have been*** X that's a "(Present) Perfect" form (he definitely seemed to be X *in the past*, and possibly still seems to be so now). But in practice no-one would bother making any such fine distinction with your cited example, because the "inspiration" referred to obviously happened in the past - it's not an *ongoing* thing.

Comment: Compare #1 *He appears to be married* and #2 *He appears to have been married*. In #2 (the perfect form), he might or might not (appear to) be married at time of utterance, but obviously he does in #1 (Simple Present + infinitive).

Answer (score 1):

appears to be inspired = appears to be in a state of inspiration

appears to have been inspired =appears to be in a state of inspiration that began in the past

In either case the author appears  to be in a state of inspiration. With the present perfect **have been**, that state of inspiration began at some time in the past.

The first, **to be**, is silent with respect to when the inspiration began. It makes no statement whatsoever in that regard.